# Unable to fetch api in local vite project. Status code with 404 error

Tags: reactjs, node.js, axios

I am getting cors error while fetching data in my local environment. i have already deployed sites in cpanel but some changes need in my project now i am not being able to see my changes in local environment this is my complete code Front-end and backend. i don't want to get axios error while deploying

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const app = express();
const vehicleRoutes = require("./routes/vehicle");
const blogRoutes = require("./routes/blog");
const mailRoutes = require("./routes/mail");
const callRoutes = require("./routes/call");

const cors = require("cors");

const cloudinary = require("cloudinary").v2;
require("dotenv/config");

app.use(
  cors({
    origin: ["https://letsdrive.com.np", "http://localhost:4000", "http://127.0.0.1:5173"],
    credentials: true,
  })
);

app.use(express.json());

app.use("/vehicle", vehicleRoutes);
app.use("/blog", blogRoutes);
app.use("/", mailRoutes);
app.use("/", callRoutes);

app.listen(4000, () => {
  console.log("Server is running on port 4000");
});

mongoose
  .connect(process.env.db_STRING, { useNewUrlParser: true })
  .then(() => {
    console.log("database connected");
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error("Error in connecting to database");
  });
```

this is my front-end where i call api. my api.js

```
import axios from "axios";

const instance = axios.create({
  baseURL: "http://localhost:4000",
  timeout: 5000, // Set your desired timeout
});


export default instance;
```

this is my vite.config.js

```
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";

https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
plugins: [react()],
});
```

I have tried all method to get my project run in vite and also in cpanel after deployed.
All i get is axios error.

Comment: What is the front end url that is displayed in address bar?

Comment: http://127.0.0.1:5173/vehicle/get-vehicles

Comment: Hello Mat J ? Help me brother ! i am seriously stuck in this problem

Comment: Open your dev tools, send the request again, look in your network tab, you will see an options request, click on it and check the request and response headers. request will have a header named origin, Check its value. In the response you should see a list of headers starting with `access-control-`. See if they are there and check its values and add a screenshot to your question maybe.